# Capture an image from a USB camera and display it in the monitor

Tags: image, camera, embedded-linux, capture

I'm trying to make an embedded-linux application that takes an image from a USB camera, write something on this image (boxes and text) and display the modified image in the monitor.

I see there are lot of frameworks and tools to do this, but I'm not sure what would be the best approach in this case, and I would love to have some directions in case someone has an advice. I was planing to use C++ but I could use be flexible on this.

Thanks
Gus

Comment: Err? What camera? Which Linux? Are you running X11?

Comment: What camera? Any supported camera... Which Linux? Embedded Linux, but I guess application should work on any distribution....Are you running X11? I'm not running anything yet...Just trying to get advice which would be the best approach. For example, should I use Video4Linux or openCV or ..... I'm looking for an advice from someone already went through this... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get `Video4Linux` working anyway because `OpenCV` uses that underneath to acquire images, so you could use that to grab the image(s). You could then add text and boxes very simply with **ImageMagick** and that could be done from command-line with no programming required. You could then display them with `feh` or **ImageMagick**'s `display` program, or any X11 viewer.

Let's say you acquired this image:

[image]

You could annotate it like this in a bash script at the command line:

```
convert input.png \
   -fill none  -stroke lime -draw "rectangle 10,50 200,300" \
   -fill white -undercolor '#00000080' -gravity SouthEast  -pointsize 72 -annotate +0+5 ' Funky Annotation '  result.png
```

[image]

`OpenCV` can take a lot of configuring and a long time to compile. You could add text and boxes in `OpenCV` but the fonts are not very configurable in OpenCV because it is more oriented towards Computer Vision (i.e. identifying objects and faces) rather generating and annotating images.

Your question is actually rather too broad for this site. Do you actually mean a single image, or a video? What sort of annotations do you mean? Is there a target frame-rate?